# Forward slash is changing to backward slash and forward slash

Tags: javascript, json

I have converted normal text into json with json_encode(data), but the problem is 
normally written `images/data.png` is converted to `images\/data.png` i have to remove this extra backslash. How is it possible

Comment: there is no need to change anything. the \/ combination is called escaping and is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

In a JSON string, `/` and `\/` are equivalent. You should not need to enforce the former syntax.

If you think you need to change them then you are either:

- Designing too much for text editors instead of JSON parsers *or*
- Being overly concerned with individual bytes

Escaping `/` provides a defence against premature script termination when you have code like this:

```
<?php
    $data = Array( "</script>" );
?>
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

That said, if you *really* want to remove it, PHP provides an option for it:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```